# Combine arbitrary number of columns into a new column of Array type in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that contains N number of columns containing integers. Some of the fields might be null as well. 
For example:

```
+---+-----+-----+
| id| f_1 | f_2 |
+---+-----+-----+
|  1| null| null|
|  2|123  | null|
|  3|124  |127  |
+---+-----+-----+
```

What I want is to combine all f-prefixed columns into a pyspark array in a new column. For example:

```
+---+---------+
| id| combined|
+---+---------+
|  1| []      |
|  2|[123]    |
|  3|[124,127]|
+---+---------+
```

The closer I have managed to get is this:

```
features_filtered = features.select(F.concat(* features.columns[1:]).alias('combined'))
```

which returns null (I assume due to the nulls in the initial dataframe). 
From what I searched I would like to use `.coalesce()` or maybe `.fillna()` to handle/remove nulls but I haven't managed to make it work.

My main requirements are that I would like the newly created column to be of type Array and that I dont want to enumerate all column names that I need to concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pyspark can be done as

```
df = df.withColumn("combined_array", f.array(*[i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('f')]))
      .withColumn("combined", expr('''FILTER(combined_array, x -> x is not null)'''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this- (In scala, but can be implemented in python with minimal change)

### Load the data

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |id| f_1 | f_2
        | 1| null| null
        | 2|123  | null
        | 3|124  |127
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(false)

    /**
      * root
      * |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- f_1: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- f_2: integer (nullable = true)
      *
      * +---+----+----+
      * |id |f_1 |f_2 |
      * +---+----+----+
      * |1  |null|null|
      * |2  |123 |null|
      * |3  |124 |127 |
      * +---+----+----+
      */
```

### Convert it to array

```scala
    df.withColumn("array", array(df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("f")).map(col): _*))
      .withColumn("combined", expr("FILTER(array, x -> x is not null)"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+----+----+----------+----------+
      * |id |f_1 |f_2 |array     |combined  |
      * +---+----+----+----------+----------+
      * |1  |null|null|[,]       |[]        |
      * |2  |123 |null|[123,]    |[123]     |
      * |3  |124 |127 |[124, 127]|[124, 127]|
      * +---+----+----+----------+----------+
      */
```